# LOOP for table function

Tags: postgresql

I'm a newbie in Posgresql

I have a table function:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION stage.get_primary_key_info(
    schemaName text, 
    tableName text
) RETURNS TABLE(constraint_name text, column_name text) AS 
$BODY$

    SELECT c.constraint_name, c.column_name
      FROM information_schema.key_column_usage AS c
      LEFT JOIN information_schema.table_constraints AS t
             ON t.constraint_name = c.constraint_name
      WHERE t.table_schema = schemaName
        AND t.table_name = tableName
        AND t.constraint_type = 'PRIMARY KEY'
    ;

$BODY$ LANGUAGE sql;
```

And I'm trying to use this function like:

```
FOR c IN (SELECT * FROM stage.get_primary_key_info(target_schema, stmt.tablename))
LOOP
    joinFields = joinFields || FORMAT('t.%s = s.%s AND', c.column_name);
END LOOP;
```

But I have this error:

> The loop variable of the tuples must be a variable of the type record
>   or tuple or a list of scalar variables

Comment: Why using a LEFT JOIN when it turns into an INNER JOIN because of your WHERE conditions?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try declaring `c` as a `record`. You are also missing a second parameter in the `FORMAT` string.

Also, take a look at [string_agg](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/functions-aggregate.html) and you might be able to skip that loop entirely. Here is an example (substituting `y` for the second parameter):

```
SELECT string_agg(FORMAT('t.%s = s.%s', column_name, 'y'), ' AND ')
  FROM get_primary_key_info(target_schema, stmt.tablename)
;
```